# Determine the Horizontal tangents of f(x)

Tags: functions, polynomials, quintics

What are the steps used to find horizontal tangents of a function f(x) as defined:
$$
f(x)=(x+1)^2 (2x-3)^3 
$$

I know we have to calculate the derivative of the function, but how do we do that? (Only looking for the real roots of the derivation = 0)

After using the Product rule $u=(x+1)^2$ and $v=(2x-3)^3$ i get a $(uv)'=uv'+u'v = 40x^4-80x^3-30x^2+90x$, but how do we find when this derivitive becomes 0 ?

Comment: This is the way. Solve for $x$ equation $f'(x)=0$.

Comment: but how do we calculate $f'(x)$?

Comment: @MichaelP.Jouanneau using the product rule.

Comment: Chain rule, product rule, logarithmic differentiation .... If it heps, let $u=(x+1)^2$ and $v=(2x-3)^3$. Compute $u'$ and $v'$ and apply $(uv)'=u'v+uv'$. Factor and simplify.

Comment: Applying  the general rules on product and composition of function, then factoring the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\frac{d}{dx}( (x+1)^2 (2x-3)^3)=0$$

> Some formulae
>   $$\text{i] }\frac{d}{dx} (x^n) = n x^{n-1}$$
>   $$\text{ii] }\frac{d}{dx}( (ax+b)^n)= a n (ax+b)^{n-1} $$
>
> As
>   $$\frac {d}{dx} (f(g(x)) = f'(g(x)). g'(x) $$
>   $$\text{where } f'(x)=\frac{d}{dx} ( f(x))$$
>
> And
>   $$\frac{d}{dx} (uv) = u \frac {d}{dx} (v) + \frac {d}{dx} (u) v $$

$$(x+1)^2 \frac {d}{dx} ((2x-3)^3)+(2x-3)^3 \frac{d}{dx} ((x+1)^2)=0$$

$$ \text{.:}(x+1)^2 3 (2x-3)^2 2 + (2x-3)^3 2(x+1) =0$$
$$ \text{.:} (2x-3)^2(x+1)(6(x+1)+2(2x-3))=0$$
$$ \text{.:}(2x-3)^2 (x+1) (6x +6+4x-6)=0$$
$$ \text{.:}(2x-3)^2 (x+1) (10x) =0$$
$$2x=3 \text{   ,   }x=-1 \text{ ,     } x=0$$
$$x=\frac{3}{2} \text{   ,  } x=-1 \text{   , } x=0$$

Comment: Thanks For the help

Answer (score 0):

HINT: use that $$f'(x)=10\, \left( x+1 \right)  \left( 2\,x-3 \right) ^{2}x$$